# Removing parts of a string returned when scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have written code in Selenium to scrape [Accor's booking website](https://all.accor.com/ssr/app/accor/hotels/london/index.en.shtml?dateIn=2021-08-20&nights=8&compositions=1&stayplus=false) after certain information has been passed. I am able to scrape and return the names of all the hotels on the resultant page with this code.

```
url = 'https://all.accor.com/ssr/app/accor/hotels/london/index.en.shtml?dateIn=2021-08-20&nights=8&compositions=1&stayplus=false'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
working = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hotel__wrapper')
for work in working:
    name = work.find_element_by_class_name('title__link').text
    name = name.strip()
    print(name)
```

This returns all of the hotel names on the page as expected, however, it's also returning an extra line with each hotel name, with the star rating of the hotel, which I don't see in the HTML markup on the page. Here is the output.

```
Sofitel London St James
5 Star rating
The Savoy
5 Star rating
Mercure London Bloomsbury Hotel
4 Star rating
Novotel London Waterloo
4 Star rating
ibis London Blackfriars
3 Star rating
Novotel London Blackfriars
4 Star rating
Mercure London Bridge
4 Star rating
Novotel London Bridge
4 Star rating
ibis Styles London Southwark - near Borough Market
3 Star rating
Pullman London St Pancras
4 Star rating
```

Is there a way to remove this extra line of text for the rating being returned with the hotel name? As I only want the hotel names as I am using the names to compare the prices on different sites. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you want Ibis Styles London Southwark to include the ' - Near Borough Market'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two string one with name and the other with rating you can split the string and can only use the hotel name part. Here is the example:

```py
for work in working:
    name_with_rating = work.find_element_by_class_name('title__link').text
    name = name_with_rating.split("\n")[0]
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the element you actually getting in `names` there are many other internal web elements.
So, to get the desired element text only you have to exclude the child elements texts.
Something like this:

```
url = 'https://all.accor.com/ssr/app/accor/hotels/london/index.en.shtml?dateIn=2021-08-20&nights=8&compositions=1&stayplus=false'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
working = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hotel__wrapper')
for work in working:
    name = work.find_element_by_class_name('title__link')
    total = name.text
    children = name.find_flements_by_xpath(".//*")
    for child in children:
        total = total.replace(child.text,'')    
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine the ideas from the other answers of getting something a bit more specific and splitting or cutting things off. I noticed that these all the elements have a title attribute with the name of the hotel + ' - New Window'.

This means you can do the following if you want the full name:

```
for work in working:
    title = work.find_element_by_class_name('title__link').get_attribute('title')
    print(title[:-13])#13 is length of ' - New Window'
```

output is:

```
Sofitel London St James
The Savoy
Mercure London Bloomsbury Hotel
Novotel London Waterloo
ibis London Blackfriars
Novotel London Blackfriars
Mercure London Bridge
Novotel London Bridge
ibis Styles London Southwark - near Borough Market
Pullman London St Pancras
```

Or, should you decide `ibis Styles London Southwark - near Borough Market` should really be `ibis Styles London Southwark`, go with the following instead:

```
for work in working:
    title = work.find_element_by_class_name('title__link').get_attribute('title')
    print(title.split(' - ')[0])
```

and get output:

```
Sofitel London St James
The Savoy
Mercure London Bloomsbury Hotel
Novotel London Waterloo
ibis London Blackfriars
Novotel London Blackfriars
Mercure London Bridge
Novotel London Bridge
ibis Styles London Southwark
Pullman London St Pancras
```